# Google Search - How to filter for WAP sites?

Tags: xhtml, mobile-website

Say I am using Google search in my mobile. I am interested to see only WAP sites (XHTML Mobile Profile). In a normal search in Google mobile, a small mobile icon is displayed next to WAP site results. I would like to see only these results.

Comment: Interesting question but not really programming related, is it?

Comment: yes, but thought geeks would know the answer

Comment: this feature doesnt exists in Google as of February 05, 2011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to http://wap.google.com/xhtml, search something and in drop-down menu select not internet but mobile